# Limit Of a Sequence involving square-Root

Tags: calculus

How can I use the fact that $\sqrt[n] {n} \to 1  $ in order to calculate the limit of the sequence:
$ \sqrt[n] {9n^2 + 30n + 17} $ ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$ \sqrt[n] {n}\leq \sqrt[n] {9n^2 + 30n + 17}\leq \sqrt[n] {56n^2}. $$

Comment: can you please explain how you got these bounds?

Comment: One of them is easy. For the other one I used that $n\leq n^2$ and $1\leq n^2$. Thus $rn\leq rn^2$ and $r\leq rn^2 \ \ \forall r,n \in \mathbb{N}$ .

Comment: Wow ! So Easy! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

For $n \gt 0$ clearly $\sqrt[n] {9n^2 + 30n + 17} \gt 1$.

Meanwhile for $n \ge 31$ you have  $30n + 17 \lt n^2$ so $$\sqrt[n] {9n^2 + 30n + 17} \lt \sqrt[n] {10 n^2 }  \lt \sqrt[n] {n^3 }  = \left(\sqrt[n] {n} \right)^3$$ and since $\sqrt[n] {n} \to 1$ you also have  $\left(\sqrt[n] {n} \right)^3 \to 1$.